# Azure API Management Services updating CORS to allow OPTIONS

Tags: azure, cors, azure-api-management

I've set up a POST endpoint in apim and I can test that it's working fine when bypassing the apim - however when I call it from my site I'm getting a 200 empty response along with `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://apim.azure-api.net/project. (Reason: CORS header “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” missing)`

I believe it's happening because "When OPTIONS request is processed as a pre-flight request and doesn't match CORS policy settings: immediately terminate the request with an empty 200 OK response" - which based on the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-cross-domain-policies the attribute `terminate-unmatched-request` is defaulted to `true` - when I try to set this in the policies to `false` it is not getting saved, for example:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cors terminate-unmatched-request="false">
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>OPTIONS</method>
                <method>POST</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    ...
```

results in:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>OPTIONS</method>
                <method>POST</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    ...
```

So I'm wondering if this needs to be set somewhere else, or if I need to update my policy differently to allow for OPTIONS preflight requests?

Comment: Non saving attribute must be a UI bug that'll need to be fixed. But this is not the source of your problem. Terminate-unmatched-requests in case if preflight requests only controls whether another cors policy will be tried. But if none of them actually matches response to preflight request still won't contain necessary headers. My suggestion would be to try to inspect preflight request to see what exactly stops cors policy from producing necessary headers in response.

Comment: To do so, open test console in Azure Portal and see the request in there. Copy it to tool that can make OPTIONS request - Fiddler works fine, change method to OPTIONS, add Access-Control-Request-Method and Origin headers and see inspector trace in response.

Comment: I moved my CORS policy from the specific Operation to the `All operations` level and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the issue was solved in the comment, just add it as an answer to help others.

> I moved my CORS policy from the specific Operation to the `All operations` level and that seemed to work.